# LINQ : Error using multiple from and Join

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-sql

The following LINQ:

```
var result = from u in db.userdetails
    from b in db.bids
    join x in db.Others on b.UserId equals x.UserId into others
    from o in others.DefaultIfEmpty()
    from p in db.Products
    where u.UserID.Equals(b.UserId)
    && p.BidId.Equals(b.BidId)
    && b.DocId == id
```

Gives me the error:

> The type of one of the expressions in the join clause is incorrect. 
>   Type inference failed in the call to 'GroupJoin'.

Comment: If I create appropriate types and add a `select` clause to your query, it compiles fine. Could you list the whole problematic query and list the types you're using? And when you're at it, it would be great if you simplified the query (and the types) so that they contain only the bits relevant to this problem.

Comment: Make sure that b.UserId and x.UserId are the same type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have better luck (and more maintainable code) by reorganizing your join and where clauses. Realize with LINQ, you don't always have to have the where clause after all of the from clauses:

```
var result = 
    from u in db.userdetails 
    join b in db.bids on u.UserID equals b.UserId
         where b.DocID == id
    join p in db.Products
         on b.BidID equals p.BidId
    join x in db.Others on b.UserId equals x.UserId into others 
    from o in others.DefaultIfEmpty() 
    Select ???
```

Then again, if you have the proper associations between your entities, you may be able to avoid all of the joins and just project into the desired shape by navigating the object graphs directly.